# correct way to echo a link with a onclick javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, onclick, echo

my question is how I can echo this the right way
because the variable in the onclick function gives out a undefined error

```
$openchat="<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='return chatWith(" . $livenaam .")'>" . $livenaam . "</a><br>";

echo $openchat;
```

I want to use it in a loop to get a list off users online for the chat

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you are missing some quotes:

```
$openchat="<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='return chatWith(\"" . $livenaam ."\")'>" . $livenaam . "</a><br>";
```

or for increased security:

```
$openchat="<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='return chatWith(\"" . htmlspecialchars($livenaam,ENT_QUOTES) ."\")'>" . htmlspecialchars($livenaam,ENT_QUOTES) . "</a><br>";
```

Comment: what, is there some button to click then?

Comment: @Richard: Click the check mark to the left of the answer, just below the vote counter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return chatWith(' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($livenaam)) . ')">' . htmlspecialchars($livenaam) . '</a><br>'
```

If `json_encode` is not available, try this:

```
'<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return chatWith(' . htmlspecialchars('"'.addslashes($livenaam).'"') . ')">' . htmlspecialchars($livenaam) . '</a><br>'
```

Comment: json_encode?? ok, interesting. I will try that if the first one diddn't work.

Comment: @Richard: `json_encode` is required to get a valid JavaScript string declaration.

Comment: @Gumbo: in both cases you need the ENT_QUOTES option to htmlspecialchars()

Comment: I have php v5.6, non the less, it gave a blank page
mayby something with the quotes. I will use the one from @mupdyke, because it did the job, thank you.

Comment: @gahooa: No, ENT_QUOTES just replaces single quotes too. But the default value for `$quote_style` is ENT_COMPAT that will replace double quotes.